# Does Neuton framework offer better ML algorithms than the ones currently known to the public?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I came across [an article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/neuton-a-new-disruptive-neural-network-framework-for-ai-applications/) about new proprietary 'Neuton' framework.

I can't find educated opinions from professionals in the field. What the framework promises feels 'too good to be true'. Is it?

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information freely available to make an intelligent discussion on the topic.

That said, do not take any benchmarks seriously unless coming from an independent and authoritative source. For example, on Neuton's [homepage benchmarks](https://neuton.ai/main), XGBoost is always better than Catboost; but if we check Yandex's [arXiv paper on Catboost](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.09516.pdf), Catboost is always better than XGBoost. Clearly, these two scenarios are contradictory on face value! While I do not believe anyone *intentionally obscures* the truth, reality might be a bit too complex to justify statements like: "*in the vast majority of cases, (algorithm X) achieves a higher level of accuracy than algorithms traditionally used for regression and classification problems.*" The marketing department might had a say there too... ;)

Don't stop studying ML just yet.

Comment: (For the record I have voted this question to close as primarily opinion-based.)